# Unable to render combo box in dialog

Tags: dojo

I want to show a popup dialog containing a dijit.ComboBox with data populated using ajax request or data store.
The problem I am facing is that the combobox is always disabled.

My selected code is:

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" id="osTypeStore" data-dojo-id="osTypeStore" url="/AjaxPopulateOS.json">
                        </div>
                        <select id="osType" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox"
                            data-dojo-props="
                                id:'osType',
                                store: osTypeStore,
                                placeHolder: 'Select a schdule type'" >
                        </select>
```

[image: combobox error]

Any ideas

Comment: For the time being, I am using html native drop downs and they work fine in the dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because there are no items in it? Is it grayed out totally - and have the Disabled class parameter set?

Check that dijit.byId('osTypeStore') returns a store and that it has items in it.

If this is the case, change your code to

```
store: 'osTypeStore'
```

Note the quotes. This forces parser to evaluate the string into a dijit - and the store might not have been initialized correctly as a true variable at the point it is read. In other words, in combobox constructor - the javascript variable is undefined.

If this does not help, try forcing to set store after onShow has run for your dialog.

```
dialog.onShow = function() {
     dijit.byId('osType').set('store', dijit.byId('osTypeStore'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing it to enabled using the property of the combo

`enabled: true,`

Other than that, check it using Firebug or debug bar or something similar :)

Comment: tried that but still not working. The same code posted in my first post is working fine when the combobox is rendered on the page and not on dialog box.